# Confused about negative stepping in python numpy

Tags: python, numpy-slicing

I am trying hard to understand every aspect of slicing, but I am still struggling.

Here is my understanding so far:

The full slice syntax is: `start:stop:step`. `start` refers to the **index** of the element which is used as a start of our slice. `stop` refers to the index of the element we should stop **just before** to finish our slice. `step` allows you to take each nth-element within a start:stop range.

Ok this all makes sense, but I am confused how the `stop` works, when we are reversing a list.

I created this brief example using Pycharm:

```
nums = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
print (nums[-2:1:-1])
```

Correct Answer in Pycharm: [80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30]

But, I would think the stop would be 10...since index[0] is 10, and index[1] is 20, and if I use the logic above... then "just before index[1] is index[0], which is 10. So why does this stop at 30 then.. which is index[2]?

Comment: Remember that you go backwards, so you stop "just before" the element with index `1`.

Comment: oh, hmm intersting. wow, I really have to warp my mind to get this

Comment: @DerekMegyesi One thing that can help: pretend you are standing at the front of a ticket line. Your boss says "go and watch the queue, stop right before you get to the man with the hat" (the man is index[1]). Where you stopped is index[2]. However, if you and your boss stand in the back of the queue and he says "go in the line and stop right before you get to the man with the black hat" you would stop at index[0]. Its all a matter of perspective on where you start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone might arrest me on this, but since you go backwards, the number just before index[1] is indeed index[2]. Look at the whole list as its reversed since you do negative stepping.

One thing that can help: pretend you are standing at the front of a ticket line. Your boss says "go and watch the queue, stop right before you get to the man with the hat" (the man with the hat is index[1]). Where you would stop is index[2]. However, if you and your boss stand in the back of the queue and he says "go in the line and stop right before you get to the man with the black hat" you would stop at index[0]. Its all a matter of perspective on where you start.

Comment: Great analogy.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. Your explanation makes sense.  I hope this posting helps someone who is learning Python slicing.